# VBA How to identify the highest value in a cell that contains changing values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell that contains a continuous data feed of changing values.  The cell can display both positive and negative numbers in “Real-Time”.  The cell’s value always starts at a positive value and trends upward.  The number goes up-and-down over time before reaching its highest point.  I need to identify the cell’s number value when it reaches its highest trend point (or highest number value).  More specifically, I need to identify the cell’s highest most positive value before the cell’s number value starts to trend consistently in the negative direction (i.e. The “Turning Point”).  I need to notify the user by displaying cell’s highest most positive value and descriptive text in a “msgbox.”  This action ends the process.

I know how to determine the maximum and large number in a range.  However, this not useful because I am not sure how to calculate the “true maximum” value of a cell with dynamic data.

Thanks.

Comment: Based on the data you presented in your question, it should be very difficult to receive some help, I think.  What "a continuous data feed of changing values" does mean? Do you have some formulas triggered by changing of the other cells in other sheets? Is it another application which change the data, from time to time? You must understand that the starting point should be to trigger the moment when the data are changed. Only after that you can find an event able to do that, a `Static` variable to keep the records (a Dictionary should be good) and then create the algorithm to evaluate the data

Answer (score 0):

You might find the `worksheet_change` function useful.  This allows you to run code each time a cell changes ([see official documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/run-macro-cells-change)).

You could set aside a cell somewhere in your workbook to hold the maximum value (perhaps set to zero to begin with), and then each time your real-time data cell changes, use the `worksheet_change` function to check if you need to update the maximum, or display a messagebox.

Comment: If the cells in discussion contain formulas, the `Change` event will never be triggered... Then, if you only 'assign a value in a cell', how can you determine the “Turning Point” and the maximum to be evaluated? Will the code consider it so for any bigger number than the assigned value?

Comment: @FaneDuru.  Point taken on the `Change` event.  I would say try it and see if it works, and if not it's back to square one.  Determining the turning point is possible if you only care about the current value being less than the value you previously put in the cell with the maximum in it.  Just do the comparison in the `worksheet_change` routine.  If you want to look at a longer-term trend, you'll need more than one cell, and maybe an extra cell to record which cell you wrote to last.

Comment: I do  not need to check if `Change` event is triggered by a change in a cell containing a formula. **I know that it is not triggered**! If any doubts, you should check it...

Answer (score 0):

The following function should cope with the described task:

```
Private Function ShowMsg(NextValue As Double) As Double
Static CurrentValue As Double
Static bMsgWasShown As Boolean
    If CurrentValue <= NextValue Then
        CurrentValue = NextValue
        bMsgWasShown = False
    Else
        If Not bMsgWasShown Then
            Call MsgBox("Max value is " & CurrentValue & " now, next value will be " & NextValue, _
                    vbInformation, "New local maximum reached")
            bMsgWasShown = True
        End If
    End If
    ShowMsg = CurrentValue
End Function
```

Call it from cell like as `=ShowMsg(G2)` where G2 is your *"a cell that contains a continuous data feed of changing values"*

Comment: JohnSUN the code you created above is utterly brilliant! It solves the 2nd part of the problem of identifying when the cells value reaches its "highest" positive point. I could use your help with the 1st part of the problem where the cell’s values...trend upward, then the #'s go up/down over time before reaching its highest value meaning the #'s can fluctuate within the # series while generally trending positive for a varying timeframe. I need a way to allow the cells value(s) to 'float' during this timeframe until they start to trend negatively. Your code addresses the negative trend problem.